# Concat vs ConcatArray RxJava

Tags: java, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-java2

Is there any difference between concat and concatArray in RxJava2 except of the number of ObservableSources?

```
Observable.concat(observable1, observable2)

Observable.concatArray(observable1, observable2, observable3, observable4)
```

The maximum number of ObservableSources in

> `concat(ObservableSource<? extends T> source1, ObservableSource<? extends T> source2, ObservableSource<? extends T> source3, ObservableSource<? extends T> sourc4)`

is 4, but in

> `concatArray(ObservableSource<? extends T>... sources)`

Is this the only difference between those two?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is only one small difference between the two: using `concatArray` will likely result in a "heap pollution" warning and requires the use of `@SuppressWarnings("unchecekd")` because of the varargs. Being only a Java 6 level library, we can't apply `@SafeVarargs`. The 2-4 argument overloads help avoid the warning.